# Multiplying the values of dictionaries with different keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

The problem of multiplying of values of two dictionaries with the same keys, I decided as follows:

```
v1={'name1': '10', 'name2': '20'}
v2={'name1': '4', 'name2': '5'}

foo = lambda dct_1, dct_2: {key: int(dct_2[key]) * int(dct_1[key]) for key in dct_2}

foo(v1, v2)
# Out: {'name1': 40, 'name2': 100}
```

How can I multiply values of two  dictionaries in the same way, but with the different keys ?

```
v1={'name1': '10', 'name2': '20'}
v2={'quantity1': '4', 'quantity2': '5'}

#OUT: {'name1':'40', 'name2': '100'}
```

Comment: does the key name from each `dict` contain the same number ?

Comment: Be very careful. Dicts are not ordered, so how do you know which elements to multiply together. Consider using collections.OrderedDict instead.

Comment: Hi! I just came up with an example. In this example, yes. But in general in this example I wanted to emphasize that different names of keys. Thank you for your comment

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you always have corresponding `nameX` and `quantityX` values, you could use a simple replace on the keys:

```
foo = lambda dct_1, dct_2: {key: int(dct_2[key.replace('name', 'quantity')]) * int(dct_1[key]) for key in dct_1}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
multiplydicts = lambda x,y: { key: str(int(v1[key]) * int(val)) for key,val in zip(v1.keys(), v2.values())}
```

Assuming that your dictionaries are the same size this should do the trick, and v2.values() will return the values of v2 in order of construction.

Answer (score 1):

you can do :

```
>>> v1={'name1': '10', 'name2': '20'}
>>> v2={'quantity1': '4', 'quantity2': '5'}   
>>> d={'name'+str(i+1) : int(v1['name'+str(i+1)])*int(v2['quantity'+str(i+1)]) for i in range(len(v1))}
>>> d
{'name2': 100, 'name1': 40}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add something to map the keys in the first dictionary to those in second. The easiest way to do it is with a third dictionary named `keymap` in the code below. The keys in the first dictionary determine the ones that will appear in the one returned.

This is needed because the order of keys in ordinary dictionaries is undefined, so you can't rely or predict what order they will appear in when you iterate over them.

```
v1={'name1': '10', 'name2': '20'}
v2={'quantity1': '4', 'quantity2': '5'}
keymap = {'name1': 'quantity1', 'name2': 'quantity2'}  # Added.

foo = (lambda dct_1, dct_2:
        {key: int(dct_2[keymap[key]]) * int(dct_1[key]) for key in dct_1})

print(foo(v1, v2))  # -> {'name1': 40, 'name2': 100}
```