# Math over list values of a dictionary with unlimited items

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe, numpy, dictionary

How do I loop through all keys list values one by one until I reach the end of the last list's array value? All lists are the same length for each key.
I mean:

```
 my_dict1 = {'c1': [10, 11, 12], 'c2': [100, 110, 120], 'c3': [200, 210, 220]}
 my_dict2 = {'c1': 3, 'c2': 1, 'c3': 2}
```

The result I need to get is:

```
result = 0.5 * ([10 * 3 + 100 * 1 + 200 * 2] + [11 * 3 + 110 * 1 + 210 * 2] + [12 * 3 + 120 * 1 + 220 * 2])
```

I checked [Multiplying the values of dictionaries with different keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46550213/multiplying-the-values-of-dictionaries-with-different-keys) and [How to Multiply list elements in dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53078068/how-to-multiply-list-elements-in-dictionary) but they did not come in handy here.

The following just worked when two dictionary have the similar keys.

```
dict1 = {2: [10, 11, 12], 2: [100, 110, 120]}
dict2 = {2: [100, 110, 120], 2: [100, 110, 120]}
result = {i :[x*y for x, y in zip(dict1[i], dict2[i])] for i in dict1.keys()}
print(result)
```

Result:

```
{2: [10000, 12100, 14400]}
```

Should I work by the NumPy or Pandas to handle it? In my real job there is a dictionary or a data frame with unknown number of keys.

Comment: Can you explain why your output has square brackets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use the key from `my_dict1` to find the multiplier in `my dict2`. From there on, you can just zip the lists and sum their items. It can be a plain Python inliner:

```
[sum(i)/2 for i in zip(*([i * my_dict2[k] for i in v] 
                         for k, v in my_dict1.items()))]
```

Above gives as expected:

```
[265.0, 281.5, 298.0]
```

You could also build 2 numpy arrays for the same operation:

```
arr1 = np.array(list(my_dict1.values()))
arr2 = np.array([my_dict2[k] for k in my_dict1])
```

Then:

```
np.sum(np.transpose(arr1) * arr2, axis=1)/2
```

gives as expected

```
array([265. , 281.5, 298. ])
```

Comment: Your answer is correct and excellent specially the second one based on the Numpy,  is what I need, I need. To know whether the second one is faster or not. can you give any suggestion?

Comment: Making the arrays could be as time consuming as doing the direct zip.  `timeit` is a popular tool for comparing things like this.

Comment: With your small example, the `zip` is 8x faster than the `numpy`.  And the `pandas` much slower.

Answer (score 0):

One way just using `zip`:

```
arr = []
for k, v in my_dict1.items():
    c = my_dict2[k]
    arr.append([i * c for i in v])
    
out = [sum(a)/2 for a in zip(*arr)]
```

Or using `pandas`:

```
out = pd.DataFrame(my_dict1).mul(my_dict2).sum(axis=1).mul(0.5)
```

Output:

```
[265.0, 281.5, 298.0]
```

Comment: Is it possible to give more explain regarding pandas?

Comment: The first solution doesn't work. unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'. Is it possible to give more explain regarding pandas?

Comment: Even the pandas solution did not work neither.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to do the math...

```
my_dict1 = {'c1': [10, 11, 12], 'c2': [100, 110, 120], 'c3': [200, 210, 220]}
my_dict2 = {'c1': 3, 'c2': 1, 'c3': 2}

result=0
for i in my_dict1:
    for j in range(len(my_dict1[i])):
        result+=my_dict1[i][j]*my_dict2[i]
result/=2
print(result)
```

Comment: It did not work correctly since here, at my_dict1[i][j]*my_dict2[i] your code multiply item of each list not first item of all lists, as first term of sum it should give: [10 * 3 + 100 * 1 + 200 * 2] and for the next iteration: [11 * 3 + 110 * 1 + 210 * 2] , ..

Comment: your code gives:

Comment: my_dict1[i][j]: 10 my_dict2[i]: 3
my_dict1[i][j]: 11 my_dict2[i]: 3
my_dict1[i][j]: 12 my_dict2[i]: 3
my_dict1[i][j]: 100 my_dict2[i]: 1
my_dict1[i][j]: 110 my_dict2[i]: 1
my_dict1[i][j]: 120 my_dict2[i]: 1
my_dict1[i][j]: 200 my_dict2[i]: 2
my_dict1[i][j]: 210 my_dict2[i]: 2
my_dict1[i][j]: 220 my_dict2[i]: 2

Answer (score 0):

It seems here using the Dataframe, Numpy and just python this question can be solved.
As Ballesta have replied based on Python:

```
[sum(i)/2 for i in zip(*([i * my_dict2[k] for i in v] 
                     for k, v in my_dict1.items()))]
```

Using Ballesta answer and Numpy:

```
arr1 = np.array(list(my_dict1.values()))
arr2 = np.array([my_dict2[k] for k in my_dict1])     
np.sum(np.transpose(arr1) * arr2, axis=1)/2
```

Or using pandas as Chris has answerd:

```
 out = pd.DataFrame(my_dict1).mul(my_dict2).sum(axis=1).mul(0.5)
```

A simpler way using the DataFrame could be:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'c1': [10, 11, 12], 'c2': [100, 110, 120]})
df = df.reset_index()  # make sure indexes pair with number of rows

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print((row['c1'] + row['c2'] )/ 2)
```